# Android phone is not mounting

Tags: android

I'm using Ubuntu from 2 weeks and I'm kinda new there. When I'm trying to connect my Android device with my PC, I'm receiving an error that tells me Unable to mount Android Phone with message Unable to open MTP device '[usb:001,014]', but the strangest is that I can see my phone internal and SD card storage. So tell me, how to fix that error, and more accurately, what's the problem causes the error?

Comment: Something to try: For me it first gave an error message but successfully remounted once I'd unlocked the screen of the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more details on which android device your using and which version of ubuntu you have?.

Give this a try

http://penzoditutto.blogspot.it/2012/12/android-mtp-devices-40-mount-scripts.html

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the device I'm trying to connect is HTC Desire X

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Note that responses should contain the actual solution, not just a link to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  HTC One running Jellybean would not mount on Ubuntu 14.04.  I fixed it by turning on USB debugging which can be found under Developer options in the settings menu.  If you can't see Developer menu you can enable it by following instructions here http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42

Comment: My USB debugging is turned on.